# Is it possible for Google Add-ons to have limited publication like Outlook Add-ins?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

I'm building a Google Add-on, and I'm wondering if it's possible to add a URL to make it limited to the public, like Outlook does.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing

Here's what I tried.

(1) Create a Google add-on with Google Apps Script. [Deploy] > [Test Deployment] > [Install Gmail], and confirm that the GAS project works on Gmail.

(2) Create a Google Cloud Platform project.

(3) On the OAuth consent page, set "User type: Internal" and scope.

(4) Specify the project number of the GCP project from the GAS project's project settings page.

(5) Enable "APIs and Services" > "Libraries" > "Google Workspace Marketplace SDK" in GCP, and set the configuration of the application.

- Check the Google Workspace add-on
- Specify the Deployment ID for the GAS project
- Display your app: Private

(6) Configure the store listing information and "Publish".

Perform installation from the app URL.At this time, you can move to the installation screen by opening the URL if it is within the same domain, but if you open the URL in a different domain, you will get a 400 error and will not be able to install. I would like to ask if it is possible to "install individually if you know the URL, etc." within a different domain.

I'd like to make my add-on available only to specific users, without having to go through the Google Add-on screening process. I would appreciate any insight you can provide. Thank you.

Comment: Only if you have a Google Workspace account. If you need further help please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: Is a Google Workspace account a case of a user having one? Or does the developer (add-on provider) have one?

Comment: Please edit the question as was suggested in the previous comment.

Comment: I have added my trial procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately still it's not possible.

As you already found, setting the OAuth Consent Screen for internal use will save your OAuth Consent Screen to go through the Google revision but it will not allow the add-on to be installed by users from a different organization.

If you are open to share the code with the users, one option might be to allow them to make a copy of your add-on and give them the directions to use it. See https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons

Related

- [Publish Google Sheets addon privately (no-verification) with new G Suite Marketplace process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60813815/1595451)

Comment: Thank you. “share the code with the users.” In other words. This way, I have to give editing rights to the add-on project to go, right? I am concerned that the code could be rewritten. Even if I give read-only permissions, it's impossible to deploy, right?